# Swinject for Swift 3.0.1

Tags: swift3, swinject

Currently [Swinject/Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) supports swift 3.0.

When will it support swift 3.0.1?

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Swinject v2 should work with Swift 3.0.1. If not, please submit [an issue to the project](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/new).